# SSRS Reports - Sort by Date, then by Time using Matrix

Tags: reporting-services

I'm having trouble with SSRS reports. Here is what I am getting currently:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the duplicate Dates under the "Date" column. So, the end result will be:
Date                          
Time                                     Comments
Thursday, June 19        12:00                      blah blabh blah
Friday, June 19                 12:00                      blah blabh blah
                                          1:29                      blah blabh blah
                                          1:30                      blah blabh blah
                                          1:31                     blah blabh blah
                                          2:30                      blah blabh blah

In summary, my goal is to have this type of layout:

Date 1
   Time1
   Time2
   Time3
Date 2
   Time1
   Time2
   Time3
Date 3
   Time1
   Time2
   Time3

I am currently using a Matrix control on the SSRS report. The Date and Time are the same field. Here's my data set:

[image]

The second column is a DATETIME type.

I saw [this MSDN article on matricies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207149%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and it has a near identical example of what I'd like to achieve. See the heading "Adding a parent group..." However, I have been unsuccessful in getting that to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your **first layout** use [`Previous`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255200.aspx) function to achieve what you need.

Set you expression on Date Textbox as

```
=iif(Fields!Date.Value=Previous(Fields!Date.Value), Nothing, Fields!Date.Value)
```

Per definition `Previous` returns the previous instance of an item within the specified scope.

To achieve the **final layout**.

Looking at your output, I am assuming you know whow to split Date and Time. After the dataset is created. Add a table and add a row group on `DateField`. Inside the group sort by Date, time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. First add Time and Comment column.
2. Create parent group on time by selecting Date field. also, select "Add Group Header".
3. In that parent group add Time field in Sorting tab
4. select the Date field in "Header" and delete the Date Column